# Excel Formula to Return Value on Closest or Equal Date

Tags: vba, excel, date

I'm working on an excel formula that will reference a table on a different worksheet in the same workbook and return a value based on the current date. Thus far I have been able to use this formula to return the value as I am intending. I've included an example table for the formula to show the methodology.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThwL0.png

```
=VLOOKUP(TODAY(),TRANSACTIONS!A:D,4,FALSE)
```

While this works, the flaw is that it will return #N/A if there are no lines which have an exact matching date. In the case of the above table, the transactions don't occur daily so if the given date returned by TODAY() doesn't match any line in the shown table, it breaks the formula. My table also contains "planned" or "expected" transactions which exist into the future meaning I can't rely on the MAX() function to provide the correct result

With that said, I am looking for a tweak to this formula that will always return a value even if the current date doesn't match any rows exactly. Using the above image as a reference, if the date returned by TODAY() were to be 2/20/17, the result it should give should be the value in D5, 1566. Conversely if the date is 2/28/17, it should return the value in D7, 1182.

Open to any an all suggestions which will achieve these results. Let me know if you need any further clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2,A:D,4,TRUE),D2)
```

so that should your date fall before the lowest in column A it'd return the first value of column D (i.e. the value in D2 cell)

Comment: This appears to be working... I am curious how though - the IFERROR function as I've come to understand it simply returns the value of D2 when the VLOOKUP doesn't return a valid value. That would normally mean that anytime the date used in the VLOOKUP is between those listed in the table, the only value I'd get in return is that of D2 but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: The 4th parameter of VLookup is set to TRUE which tells Excel not to look for an exact match (As FALSE would do). See MSDN documentation for further details. Since I solved your question you may want to mark answer as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX MATCH instead of VLOOKUP within the IFERROR already suggested above.

Comment: Here is the formula as you suggested. However when it's showing as an invalid INDEX MATCH function call thus breaking the formula. Can you provide any suggestions to correct it?  

     `=IFERROR(INDEX MATCH(TODAY(),A:D),D2)`

Comment: The purpose of the IFERROR is to display something instead of NA or ERROR. The way it works is: 
=IFERROR(formula you want to use , formula or value you want instead of NA or ERROR).
INDEX MATCH is set up differently to VLOOKUP so you cannot follow the same string:
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(TODAY(),A:A,0))
You should be able to work out what each bit means except the 0 at the end. This can be a -1, 0 or 1. Excel should tell you what these mean.
The formula I would use would be:
=IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(TODAY(),A;A,0)),INDEX(D:D,MATCH(TODAY(),A:A,-1)))